# Unable to Playback on SAP Web Dyn Pro Screens in LoadRunner 11.0

Tags: loadrunner

Presently I am trying to record an Order to Cash Application which interacts with SAP GUI (first) and SAP web dyn pro screens using HP Load Runner (11.0). I am able to record on SAP GUI and SAP web dyn pro screen as well but while replaying back the SAP GUI part plays perfect but when it comes to SAP web dyn pro screen it just exits out without playing back anything.
I tried correlating sap-wd-secure-id and sap-context-id but the moment it comes to SAP web dyn pro screens it exits out.

Can anyone please help me with this as I am stuck up badly on this.
Appreciate your help!!!

Comment: You need to be VERY careful when scripting webdynpro. ALL the sap-* parameters need to be correlated, and most manually. Good luck! (I dislike SAP WebDynPro for these aforementioned reasons)

Answer (score 0):

Record twice, perhaps thrice, and then diff the scripts.   By your description you appear to be missing a correlated variable related to session or state.   By recording multiple times and examining the differences in the produced scripts you should see the dynamic entities which are changing which need to be addressed.